# Random sample a percentage of rows without repetition in R

Tags: r, sample

I have population data with age and gender characteristics, and I'm trying to populate another column with employment type based on other data have. I've used 'sample' to select a sample of of the population who work part time and then I will add this data as a new column, but I have yet to figure out how to ensure those selected are not reselected in the next sample for a different employment type.

At the moment I have the following which is for 23% of Male in a certain age group:

```
PT=my.df[sample(which(my.df$Age=="15" & my.df$Gender=="Male"), round(0.23*length (which(my.df$Age=="15" & my.df$Gender=="Male")))),]
```

And an example of my output looks like this:

```
         Edinburgh.ID    Age    Gender
2445         2445        15      Male
2477         2477        15      Male
2469         2469        15      Male
2485         2485        15      Male
2487         2487        15      Male
2483         2483        15      Male
```

I now want to select the next x% from the same age and gender group who have a different employment type. If I just change the 0.23 to another percentage, in some cases, the same IDs are coming out but I want individual IDs in each sample.

Comment: why can't you just sample (23 + x)% without replacement, then just use the first 23% and the last x% separately for your needs?

Comment: How many employment types do you have and what shares do you want them to have? If you know you want counts of 100, 200, 300 for types unemployed, part-time, full time, then create your assignment vector and jumble it for your new column: `sample(c(rep("unemployed", 100), rep("parttime", 200), rep("fulltime",300)))` Obviously, you'll have to compute your 100, 200, 300 first if you only know percentages and haven't thought as far as counts...

Comment: I have 10 employment types and the shares vary depending on age groups and gender. I am using census data and my assignment needs to be as accurate as possible. For example one age group has 23.2%, 5.5%, 0.5%, 11.6%, 58.6%, 0.5%, and 0% for remaining employment types. Then a different age group will have different percentages (or counts, whatever is easier). I am trying to distribute employment type by age, gender, and eventually ethnicity.

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package gives the possibility to randomly sample in percentage with(out) replacement.

```
library('dplyr')
sample_frac(df, size = percentage, replace = FALSE)
```

then you can adjust your constraints on age and gender accordingly.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Can I adjust my constraints within that one line of code or do I need to do this separately? I've added to the code but keep getting errors, I'm not sure if it's because it's not possible or my R skills aren't up to scratch!

Comment: The `sample_frac` is only to allow you to select in percentages with(out) replacement. The data sets you want to sample from have to be already defined before, that is, you first adjust `df` to what you want (according to gender and/or age) and then sample. In principle you might also do it in one line as `sample_frac(df[age == ..., gender == ], size = ...)` but I would discourage to do so as it makes the line somewhat unreadable.

Comment: Thanks again @Gennaro. All seems to be working but unfortunately when I do the next sample is it picking up rows in previous the sample. I'm wondering if I need to also use something 'unique' or 'distinct'. Or if it is easier to remove each sample from the 'data.frame' as go then sample again.

Comment: When you sample from your initial set you may want to assign this sample to a new variable, so that you can sample from within that (instead of sampling from the initial one again).

Comment: It's the initial set I need to keep sampling rather than within the sample. For example I need 23% assigned to part time, 6% to full time, 12% unemployed and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a data.frame describing the employment statistics for a given group and sample from it. Here is an approach in base R.

```
# Generate some data
N = 1000
my.df <- data.frame(Age = rep("15", N),
                    Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), N, TRUE),
                    Activity = rep("", N),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(my.df)
# Age Gender Activity
# 1  15 Female         
# 2  15   Male         
# 3  15   Male         
# 4  15 Female         
# 5  15   Male         
# 6  15 Female        

# employment statistics for the group age = "15" and gender = "Male"
employment <- data.frame(activity = letters[1:5],
                         prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
employment
# activity prob
# 1        a  0.1
# 2        b  0.1
# 3        c  0.2
# 4        d  0.5
# 5        e  0.1

# Assign activities
set.seed(35)
id   <- which(my.df$Age == "15" & my.df$Gender == "Male")
my.df[id, "Activity"] <- sample(employment$activity, length(id),
                      replace = TRUE, prob =  employment$prob)

table(my.df[my.df$Gender=="Male", "Activity"])/length(id)
# a         b         c         d         e 
# 0.1135903 0.1054767 0.1805274 0.4665314 0.1338742
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I'm getting a few errors or warnings but I'm new to R so I think it's just because I need to make a couple of adjustments to suit the data. I'll keep playing with it but this a great starting point for me. Thank you again.